# Add to a list of a generic List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

Let say I have a `List<T> ListOfParts = new List<T>`; inside a class public class Car. I want to add a new 'Part' object to the `ListOfParts` list. I get the following error (see below). What am I doing wrong ?

```
public class Car
{
    public List<T> ListOfParts = new List<T>();
      :
      :
}

// Main ...
 Car<Part> myCar = new Car<Part>();
 Part myPart = new Part();
 myCar.ListOfParts.Add(myPart);  // <<< Error here
```

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(T) has some invalid arguments (CS1502)

Comment: Why do you have `Car<T>`? What's the purpose of `T` in the declaration of `Car`? It seems that you misunderstand how to use generics - `Car<Part>` doesn't make sense to me at all. Having a `Car` doesn't imply any specific `Part` - `Car`-s are made of `Part`-s but `Car`-s are not kinds of `Part`-s.

Comment: No, you aren't... http://ideone.com/tJN19G The only problem I see is that you are using `mrCar.ListOfParts` instead of `myCar`

Comment: You misspelt `mrCar`. Otherwise it should compile. Maybe something you didn't show us. `class Part`?

Comment: Do I not need <T> as part of the definition of class car<T> so the ListOfParts use of <T> works? Otherwise the compiler says it doesn't know what T is

Comment: Please post real code. Adding `<T>` after `class Car` is all that's required to get your code working (typo, I assume). https://dotnetfiddle.net/4pvLd6 - there's no error where you say there is.

Comment: @xxbbcc The OP's original code seemed to make perfect sense to me. A `Car<T>` (read "car of T") would hold a list of `T`s. `Car<Part>` is one specific reification of the generic type `Car<T>`. What part is so hard to understand?

Comment: @user1930748 [Here](http://ideone.com/eQCxNW) is a demo of your code (from before you edited it), exactly as is (with the missing classes added), working with no problems. Could you elaborate on what the issue is?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Exactly, and in fact the OP *did* have the `<T>` in the original revision.

Comment: @Asad I have no idea what you mean by `Car<T>`. What other types would make sense to you, other than `Part`? (I can imagine some kind of `CarX<T>` type but the OP context is clearly about storing parts.) While `Part` may be derived from to create various custom (specialized) parts, why would that change the `Car` type? (In addition, the OP had a chance to respond to my comment questions, but never did.) What would `Car<int>` mean? Or `Car<HttpContext>`? (I know these are extremes.)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to declare your class `Car` as a generic type:

```
public class Car<T>
{
    public List<T> listOfParts = new List<T>();
}
```

This allows you to pass a generic type parameter that needs to be defined *at compile-time*.

The type you are assigning as you declare a `Car<>` variable will be passed to the member `listOfParts`.

```
Car<Integer> carWithIntegerList;
Car<Owners> carWithOwnersList;
// etc..
```

**Note:**

One of the comments stated this already: You should not do this that way. You should rather declare the generic type of the list *inside* the class like this:

```
public class Car
{
    public List<Part> listOfParts = new List<Part>();
}

public class Part
{
    // ..
}

public class CustomPart extends Part
{
    // ..
}

// 

Car car = new Car();
car.listOfParts(new Part());
car.listOfParts(new CustomPart());
```

In addition: You might want to make `listOfParts` private and write a getter function for it:

```
public List<Part> getListOfParts() { 
    return this.listOfParts; 
}
```

and if you notice I am using a lower-case letter for the member name. Take a look at [code conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) and also (see my comment below) at [polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_polymorphism.htm) that explains why adding a `CustomPart` will still work.

Comment: The problem is I would like to be able to derive a class from Parts (eg: CustomParts : Parts) and add this to the ListOfParts. But the compiler will complain that CustomParts is not a 'Parts' object.

Comment: @user1930748 no, if custompart does subclass parts there should be no issue adding it to listofparts.

Comment: @user1930748 Like Andy said, this is not a problem if you have `class CustomParts extends Parts`. In that case you can still use `List<Parts>` as the type for your member. Take a look at [polymorphism](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_polymorphism.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do so my answer goes with the assumption that you're trying to model a `Car` class in the 'usual' manner. If that's not what you're after, this answer probably doesn't apply.

The list of parts in your `Car` class doesn't need to be generic - cars don't have different *types* of tires - they have different *models* of tires, but they're still *all* tires. The same goes for engines, seats, etc. - all these components are just subtypes of `Part`. You can have a general `Part` class and then you can derive your specialized car parts from that - maybe `Tire`, `Engine` (then `V4Engine` and `V6Engine`, ...), etc.

```
public class Car
{
    public List<Part> ListOfParts = new List<Part>();

    // ...
}

public abstract class Part
{
    // ...
}

public class Tire : Part
{
    // ...
}

// Main ...
Car myCar = new Car ();
Tire myTire = new Tire ();

myCar.ListOfParts.Add ( myTire );
```

Note that `Part` is an abstract class - it doesn't make much sense to just add a 'part' to a car - a car is really made of specific parts which all share a common aspect: they're all parts.

This is also not necessarily the best way to represent cars (it's not necessarily bad either) - having an open list of `Part`-s makes it hard to enforce validation. With an open list, the caller can add 7 tires to a car that should only have 4 or add 3 steering wheels when most cars only have 1.

Since the list is publicly accessible, your `Car` instance has no way to know about changes to its list of parts. It's typically better to prevent bad data from forming (prevent adding invalid items), rather than trying to weed out bad data after the fact (going through the list and counting each part, making sure you have the right number of each).